# Join and Update in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I have a users table in my database and I want to have relationship with two other table(comments, posts).

When I leave a comment it gets posted according to the id and its username; the same goes with the posts, if an user publishes a post its username goes to the database, now lets say that this user wants to update his info, for example his email, website, avatar img, etc.

All the new data should update itself in the other two tables according to the users.id/user_id. I'm sure this has something to do with join and I'm actually doing that but nothings happen.

Here is my code:

```
public function update($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->select('users.*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.username = users.username','inner');
    $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.user_id = users.id','inner');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.user_id = users.id','inner');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.username = users.username','inner');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.avatar_img = users.avatar_img','inner');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.email = users.email','inner');
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.website = users.website','inner');
    // Update info in all tables according to user id.
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
}
```

AS you can observe in the code above I'm trying to select everything from the user table and I'm trying to join it with the other table to then update its info.

I hope you guys can help me, thanks.

Here are the three tables that I'm trying to join
**A bit of the Users table**
[image]

**Posts table**
[image]

**Comments table**
[image]

Comment: I am curious, what does that do? You must get "something" happening!

Comment: And what is in $data? Can you share an example of that. And why even perform the Select query when you are performing an update?

Comment: update each table data separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you store all the information in all tables?

Wouldn't it be easier to store the personal data in the user-table, the data connected to a post in the post-table, and the data of a comment in the comment table?

And when you show a post you fetch the user-data out of the user-table.

So there would be no need to update the way you want to update that.

If you want to stick with your way of storing the data I think you are thinking too far. You don't need a join to update data. Just update each table separatly with the data you are sending to the function.

Means:

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->update('users', $data);

$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->update('posts', $data);

$this->db->where('user_id', $id);
$this->db->update('comments', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

YOUR CONTROLLER

```
 public function update_data()
{
    //Use $id and $data according to your database table's requirements 
    $update_user = $this->model-name->update_user($id, $data);
    $update_post = $this->model-name->update_post($id, $data);
    $update_comments = $this->model-name->update_comments($id, $data);
    if($update_user )
    {
      //Do what you want
    }
     if($update_post )
    {
      //Do what you want
    }
     if($update_comments )
    {
      //Do what you want
    }
}
```

YOUR MODEL

```
public function update_user($id, $data)
{ 
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  return $this->db->update('users', $data);
 }

public function update_post($id, $data)
{ 
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  return $this->db->update('posts', $data);
 }

  public function update_comments($id, $data)
{ 
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  return $this->db->update('comments', $data);
 }
```